# How do I get to display image in my flutter app? What i'm doing is not working

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm new to flutter app development and trying to display and image in the app and below is the error I get when I run the app and my code snippet too, help a novice please.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone XR in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           21.3s
Syncing files to device iPhone XR...
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
flutter: Unable to load asset: assets/images/GEJ.jpg
flutter:
flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
flutter: #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
flutter: #1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:433:44)
flutter: <asynchronous suspension>
flutter: #2      AssetBundleImageProvider.load (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:418:14)
flutter: #3      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:285:105)
flutter: #4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:157:22)
flutter: #5      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:285:82)
flutter: (elided 13 frames from package dart:async)
flutter:
flutter: Image provider: AssetImage(bundle: null, name: "assets/images/GEJ.jpg")
flutter: Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#266bb(), name: "assets/images/GEJ.jpg",
flutter: scale: 1.0)
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Code Snippet:

```
child: Image.asset(
                     'assets/images/GEJ.jpg',
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
    
                 ),
```

PS: Below is my `pubspec.yaml` info:

> ```
>    environment:
>      sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"
>    
>    dependencies:
>      flutter:
>        sdk: flutter
>
>      cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
>    
>    dev_dependencies:
>      flutter_test:
>        sdk: flutter
>
>    flutter:
>
>    assets:
>      - assets/images/GEJ.jpg
> ```

[Also when i indent the asset: one more, it says The assets does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HoEg.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make new folder called `images` in your `assets` folder and have your image file in it. Like this:

```
com.yourpackage.app
  - assets
    - images
      - GEJ.jpg
```

Once done, you need to run `flutter packages get` command in terminal window or you can use IDE option that reads `Packages get` when you're in `pubspec.yaml` file

Comment: Yipiii! Did work, thanks. I was putting the "assets" folder within the "lib" folder. Again, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for telling me how to accept answers. I was actually looking for how to. 